# Do I need to file taxes for multi-member LLC with no activity (State of NJ)

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, new-jersey

I know there are several threads to this end on here - I have read them all and am still in need of some assistance.

I am an owner of a mulit-member LLC that was established this past year in the state of NJ. We have zero income and zero expenses.

Do we need to file state taxes with NJ? There is a $225 fee per member on the NJ tax form, so it is a really big deal if we need to file. I am struggling to figure this out and your help is very much greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I would almost certainly think so; who would they know you had no income if you don't file?  In VT it doesn't matter if you make money or not, you still pay at least $250 in income tax (even if you had not income for the year).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [NJ Division of Taxation](http://www.state.nj.us/treasury/taxation/partnotice.shtml), every partnership "that has income from sources in the State of New Jersey, or has a New Jersey resident partner" must file.

So it sounds like if you have any partners who live in New Jersey you have to file.

Comment: But we don't have any income from the LLC

Comment: Yeah but the instructions say "OR has a NJ resident partner" so it seems like if EITHER of those are true, you have to file.

Comment: just dissolve the llc. You don't need an llc to have a business.

Comment: NJ is gross for charging this.